# Spring Integration SFTP - Getting configurations from XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Let say I have these configurations in my xml,

```
<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="sftpOutbound"
            channel="sftpChannel"
            auto-create-directory="true"
            remote-directory="/path/to/remote/directory/"
            session-factory="cachingSessionFactory">
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

How can I retrieve the attributes i.e, remote-directory in Java class ?

I tried to use `context.getBean('sftpOutbound')` but it returns EventDrivenConsumer class which doesn't have methods to get the configurations.

I'm using spring-integration-sftp v 4.0.0.

Comment: I guess that what you get is also a https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound/SftpMessageHandler.html Have you tried using its method getIntegrationProperties()?

Comment: I think that method is protected and I cannot access that method from other class. Also I'm using spring integration v4.0.0. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Ok. v.4.0.0 What about method getRemoteFilename? https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/4.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/gateway/SftpOutboundGateway.html Sftp Outbound Channel Adapters seems to have been replaced by Sft Outbound Gateway

Answer (score 1):

I am actually more concerned with why you wan to access it. I mean the remote directory and other attributes will come with the headers of each message, so you will have access to it at the Message level, but not at the level of Event Driven Consumer and that is by design, hence my question.

Comment: For now I just want to retrieve the remote directory, so that I can use the filename fullpath for something else like saving into db. That means I can only get the full path after I send the message is it ?

Comment: Well, there is more then one way to address "save to db" or any other "side reaction".  First, the 'remote-directory' is an attribute that is hard coded and is typically set through the external property, which means any component who is interested in this property's value can get it. You can also use channel interceptor. etc., but not directly via EDC and as said it is by design. In any event, based on my understanding the external property is the best way for you, but as I said it would be better if you explain your use case. It feels now you are attempting to do something wrong